# Hiding google reCAPTCHA v3 badge

Tags: recaptcha

Google is stating:

> You are allowed to hide the badge as long as you include the reCAPTCHA
> branding visibly in the user flow. Please include the following text:
>
> This site is protected by reCAPTCHA and the Google
> [Privacy Policy](https://policies.google.com/privacy) and
> [Terms of Service](https://policies.google.com/terms) apply.

But what happens if I hide the badge and also don't show the above branding text?
Would the reCaptcha still work?

Comment: Yeap, it will still work no matter if you hide the badge or not . (hide via CSS: `.grecaptcha-badge {visibility: hidden !important;}`